# How to produce produce gel for ocean?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, absorption, desiccation

```
Chemical Formula    CaCo
Molecular weight    89
Purity  Minimum 50%
Properties / Specification

Physical Appearance White, off white prills.
Calcium Carbonate   50% Min
Magnesium Chloride  2.0% Max
Calcium Hydroxide   0.3% Max
Calcium Sulfate 0.3% Max
Water Insoluble 0.5% Max
pH (5% w/v solution)    8.5-10.5
```

Answer (score 1):

If the calcium chloride is already anhydrous (as shown by the amount of water, $\ce{H2O}$, by weight percent), i.e. has little water, then there's nothing to do but package it in a manner that when it liquefies from absorbing water from the air, it won't drip on containers below. For an example, [with a plastic box or pail below](https://detail.en.china.cn/provide/p103342063.html).

If there is substantial moisture alerady in the desiccant, then you'd need to dry it by heat (or find another source of calcium chloride).

Be careful pouring it into bags, as that generates irritating, though not poisonous, dust. Use a respirator mask and goggles if working with large amounts.